# Recurrence Relation of Recursive Functions That

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity

For several weeks, I have been focusing on learning time complexity, especially when it comes to recursive functions. While I generally understand it, certain scenarios have brought me some confusion. I will try to explain one such instance of confusion by demonstrating a rudimentary example. Suppose we have the dummy recursion function below, where input `l` is a Python list:

```
def foo(l):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return 0
    return 1 + foo(l[1:])
```

My confusion arises from the line in which we execute `l[1:]` and how it relates to the recurrence relation of this function. Moreover, as I have learned to this point, creating a sub-list (as we are doing here) requires `M` computations, where `M` is the length of the sub-list. In other words, list slicing has a time complexity of `O(M)`, where `M` is the length of the sub-list. When we are writing our recurrence relation, though, how do we account for this?

Below is my best guess:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n - 1 + 4    
                                                         
T(0) = 4
```

I will explain my reasoning for the first equation step by step. First, the `4` represents the constant operations that take place during each recursive call. For instance, the time it takes to run the first line or the time it takes to run the return line will remain constant across calls, regardless of input size; I arbitrarily assigned this value to be `4`, though it could be any constant. Next, the `n-1` value represents the number of operations required to slice the original list (of length `n`) into a list with one less element. As mentioned in my previous dialogue, list slicing takes `M` operations, where `M` is the length of the sub-list. In this case, if our initial input is `n`, then our sub-list is `n-1`, and the creation of such a sub-list requires `n-1` computations. Finally, `T(n-1)` represents the fact that a function call with an argument of size `n` will call itself once, passing a list of size `n-1`.

Is this logic right? That is, is the term `n-1` in the recurrence relation appropriate given the fact that we are creating a sub-list of `n-1` elements?

Comment: "Recurrence Relation of Recursive Functions That".... that what? Where's the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after some thinking, I have come up with this:

1. The constant '4' represents operations performed during each call, including checking the length of the list and the return.
2. The slicing operation `l[1:]` creates a new list with `n-1` elements. This operation takes linear time, not `n-1` operations.
3. The term `T(n-1)` is the time taken for the recursive call with an argument of size `n-1`. I assume the recursive call takes the same time as solving a smaller problem.

The correct answer for the time complexity of `foo` is: `T(n) = T(n-1) + n + 4`

To solve this, you could use methods like substitution or recursion trees. You would find that the time complexity of the `foo` function is `O(n^2)` (AKA quadratic), as it makes 'n' recursive calls, and each call involves slicing the list, which takes linear time.

Thank you for all the details you provided! It made it easier to help.